# Loading with Overlay over the whole page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, loading

I use Jquery Mobile in my application.
How can i configure the loading wiget to show a dark overlay behind the loading gif over the whole page?

Thanks for replays.

best reguards,
Kevin

Answer (score 2):

Before the ajax call -

```
$('.waitpage').show();
```

and at time of completion -

```
$('.waitpage').hide();
```

HTML -

```
<div class="waitpage" id="waitpage" style="display: none;">
    <div class="waitpage-box">
        <p>
            <img alt="(Loading)" src="/Content/images/loader.gif">
            <span>Please Wait...</span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS -

```
.waitpage {
    background: url(../images/blockUI.png) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0);
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
}

.waitpage-box {
    background: none repeat scroll center center #fff;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 #666;
    left: 44%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 16px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    top: 46%;
    z-index: 99999;
}
.waitpage-box p img {
    color: #d0622b;
    float: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.waitpage-box p span {
    float: left;
    font-size: .8125em;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 6px 0 0 12px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this tutorial or different ways to accomplish that:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/11/07/css-overlay-techniques/

And then play with the `z-index` property to place it behind the loading.

I personally would do it with a fixed element. For example:

```
.overlay{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 101;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this fiddle, does it help?

http://jsfiddle.net/5GB6B/1/

```
.ui-loader-background {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    display:none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index:100;
}

.ui-loading .ui-loader-background {
    display:block;
}
```